# SpringAndroidSpiceRequest how show response

Tags: android, response

I use SpringAndroidSpiceRequest and execute queries using it. I accept the answers directly to objects, everything is fine as long as the structures are the same. If converting from json fails, the error takes off. My question is: can I somehow see the answer before it is expanded in terms of objects?